# How many files can rm delete at once?

Tags: rm, arguments

One of my friends wanted to have more logs in the `/var/log/` directory, and after some time of using the system, he tried to access the folder and list it, but instead he got the following error:

```
bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

Does anyone know how many files can be added to this `rm` list?

Comment: Part of the question is probably a duplicate, but the answer also contains a solution to the task at hand, while the other question does not.

Comment: Yes it solves partially. But I think it's enough for me.

Answer (score 6):

The maximum length of the command line is set by the system and is sometimes 128KiB.

If you need to remove many, many files, you need to call `rm` more than once, using `xargs`:

```
find /var/log -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm --
```

(Careful, this will find and delete all files in the subdirectories of `/var/log` etc. - if you do not want that use `find /var/log/ -type f -maxdepth 1`).  The `find` lists the files, 0-delimited (not newline), and `xargs -0` will accept exactly this input (to handle filenames with spaces etc.), then call `rm --` for these files.

Use `rm -f --` (**with caution**) if you are asked whether files should be removed, and you are sure you want to remove them.

Comment: Ok, so it's for all commands, not just the one.

Comment: The limit is one for the current shell, for the current command line.  If you open many shells each will have this limit.  `xargs` will call `rm` as many times as necessary, distributing the many file names that are fed to it by the `find` command such that the limit is not exceeded (each of the `rm` commands will be limited by the commandline length limit).