# In a folder with many files how to do rm on lots of them

Tags: command-line, rm, arguments

I just experimented a bit in linux and ended up getting very many files in one and the same folder. Now when I try to do

> rm -f folder/*.png

I get

> -bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long

Is there some easy way to get past this?

---

**Own work:**

I suppose I could make an ugly script which loops through rm on the result of something like

> ls /folder/ | head -100 | grep ".*\.png"

But really, there must be an easier Gnu way to do it?

Comment: Related: [How many files can rm delete at once](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209749/how-many-files-can-rm-delete-at-once) (look at the `find ... | xargs ...` answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
ls -1 | grep "\.png$" | xargs -L 50 rm -f
```

This will match (and remove) only files ending with `.png`.

Comment: Ah, xargs what a nice command it seems.

Comment: I usually use find for deleting an unusually large number of files.

Comment: `find . -name .php -exec rm -f {}` would work as well.  I generally prefer pipelines to find because that's how my brain works

Comment: I have edited your answer with `grep '\.png$'`, to make sure it won't match file names like `abcpng` nor `a.png.bkp`. Also, in your previous comment you wrote `php` instead of `png`, but I know it was just a typo (=

Comment: Thanks.  Can you guess what language I've been scripting in today :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `rm -f folder/*.png` or even simpler `rm *` then the shell (not rm) will expand the * to all relevant files. It will then call rm with all the filenames expanded. (e.g. if will do a `rm filename1 filename2 filename3 filename4 filename5 filename6 filename7 .... filename12345'

If that list is too long to pass you will get this error.

Solution: Split it in smaller chunks, or do not use the shell. E.g. find with --delete is a nice option.

- `find /path/to/file -name "*.PNG" -delete \;`
- `find /path/to/file -name "*.PNG" -exec rm \;` (runs rm once for each file)
- `find /path/to/file -name "*.PNG" -delete +`   (groups them into chunks just small enough to pass to rm)

The first option is the one I usually use. First tested with -print.